# Django and Gunicorn issues

Tags: django, wsgi, gunicorn

I can't run my Django application on my Ubuntu server. I'm following this tutorial http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/ and am pretty sure I have all of the dependencies installed.

It works fine when I run:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

However when I run:

```
gunicorn djangoproject:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8001
```

I'm running into this error:

```
2014-07-23 04:50:16 [19676] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.4
2014-07-23 04:50:16 [19676] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8001 (19676)
2014-07-23 04:50:16 [19676] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-07-23 04:50:16 [19681] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19681
Failed to find application: 'djangoproject'
2014-07-23 04:50:16 [19681] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19681)
2014-07-23 04:50:16 [19676] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-07-23 04:50:16 [19676] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Zee

Comment: what is "instaryde" ?. The error is django project not finding.

Comment: Try this in your procfile web: gunicorn instaryde.wsgi

Comment: Sorry it should say djangoproject

Comment: ok then did u tried what i suggested ?

Comment: @rajasimon thanks for the quick response, but it didn't work. I just created Procfile and added that text. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: runserver or foreman start commands  discover this application via the ``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting. So setting up wsgi correctly

Comment: Ok, but is there something else I can show you to help debug the problem? I'm of what you've said, but I can't seem to get gunicorn to discover the app.

Comment: Alright so I got it to by installing foreman and using that Procfile with `foreman start`. But I'm very curious to know why it's not running the server or finding the app, with the `gunicorn djangoproject:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8001` command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your wsgi file path

gunicorn djangoproject.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8001

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I hosted my site on Ubuntu server. I followed up this tutorial which perfectly worked for me

[Installing Django application with nginx ......](https://www.shellvoide.com/hacks/installing-django-application-with-nginx-mysql-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-vps)

I got the same error when I first tried with Digital ocean tutorial. The problem is gunicorn doesn't able to find your project. Try adding --chdir /address/to/path option to your gunicorn settings

Answer (score -1):

- Goto to project directory, where you see `manage.py` file
- Run following code

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 djangoproject.wsgi
```

If you want to access the site from public URL, please add following code in settings.
`djangoproject/djangoproject/settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```